# Find the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^4+4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Find the Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^4+4$.

I don't understand my prof's notes on this subject. If someone could walk me through how to do this and questions like this, that would be wonderful.

Comment: What about the notes don't you understand?

Comment: They're just too disjointed and full of typos, and this particular section was a page stating the Fundamental Theorem of Galois theory. I couldn't glean much from it to help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay.

1. Find the roots. This should be easy.
2. Show $\Bbb Q(i)$ is the splitting field of $x^4+4$.
3. It's degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$, so there is $1$ nontrivial symmetry.
4. Conjugation is a nontrivial symmetry.

(Sorry, in my original version I didn't anticipate as nice of numbers would turn up; this makes the choice of $4$ for the constant term a bit serendipitous here.)

Comment: The roots are $\pm(1-i)$ and $\pm(1+i)$. Isn't  $x^4+4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes those are the roots. No $x^4+4$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. If you wanted to find the factorization over $\Bbb R$ you'd pair conjugate roots and see where that takes you; do that and you'll see the real irreducible factors happen to have integer coefficients.

Comment: Actually my original list was for when the roots didn't come out as nicely as they do, sorry.

Comment: No, how are they equal?

Comment: A splitting field is the smallest field extension of a field over a polynomial (where the coefficients of that polynomial are in the field) such that the polynomial decomposes into linear factors.

Comment: Praphulla, I think you meant splitting when you said fixed. I don't see how asking which roots of $f(x)$ are in the base field accomplishes anything.

Comment: That makes more sense! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^4+4=x^4+4x^2+4-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2). $